# How to extract the keyword properties of a PDF URL using IBM Watson Explorer?

Tags: pdf, keyword, ibm-watson, extract

I want to extract the keyword value of a PDF from a PDF link. I am crawling a page which contains a link to some PDFs. I want to build a virtual document where I have to enqueue those PDF. I don't want to crawl the content of those PDFs, but I only want to extract the keyword from those PDFs. When I open those PDF links with inspect source, it does have a keyword field. But it doesn't have any value of the keyword. It looks like this:

```html
 <div class="row">
 <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_keywords">Keywords:</span> <p id="keywordsField">-</p>
 </div>
```

Is there any way to extract a keyword from the PDFs? I see those PDFs have keywords, when I download those PDF's, Open PDF properties and keyword have some value.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8NLW_10.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.dataexpl.engine.tut.virt.doc/t_cc-build-virt-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an out of the box way, but you can try to implement a crawler plugin or your own crawler. There are hooks to add extract metadata and add them to the index, for example in a crawler plugin you can do something like this

```java
@Override
    public CrawledData updateDocument(CrawledData crawledData) throws CrawlerPluginException {

        List<FieldMetadata> metadataList = crawledData.getMetadataList();
        String MyPDFProperty= getFromOriginalContent(crawledData.getOriginalContents());
//getFromOriginalContent method you need to implement for your PDF document

          if (metadataList == null) {
             metadataList = new ArrayList<FieldMetadata>();
          }                       

FieldMetadata pdfFieldMetaData = new FieldMetadata("pdfextractedpropertyr", MyPDFProperty);
                metadataList.add(pdfFieldMetaData);
                crawledData.setMetadataList(metadataList);

            } catch (ClientServicesException e) {

                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                throw new CrawlerPluginException(e);
            }
          }
          return crawledData;
    }
```